# Static vs dynamic memory allocation for thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've written a sample program to show my problem - I don't understand why `firstVersion()` is working properly, and `secondVersion()` gives me error :`terminate called without an active exception Aborted`. Thanks for answers! 
Here's the code :)

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
const int threadCount = 100;
int N = 1;


void f() {
    N++;
}

void firstVersion() {
    thread * t[threadCount];
    for(int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
        thread * ti = new thread{f};
        t[i] = ti;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
        t[i]->join();
        delete t[i];
    }
}


void secondVersion() {
    thread * t[threadCount];
    for(int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
        thread ti{f};
        t[i] = &ti;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
        t[i]->join();
}

int main() {
    //firstVersion();
    secondVersion();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because of object lifetime. `t[i]` immediately becomes a dangling pointer at the end of the loop body.

Comment: perhaps you should review C++ object model before jumping to something like threading

Comment: There's no need for those pointers. Just use an array of thread objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second version fails because the lifetime of thread ends at the end of your for loop before you call `join()`.

```
void secondVersion() {
    thread * t[threadCount];
    for(int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
        thread ti{f};        // local object of thread
        t[i] = &ti;
    }                        // the object dies without a join()
```

Your example can be simplified as:

```
void SomeFunc() {}

int main()
{
    std::thread* tp; 
    //{ 
        std::thread t{SomeFunc};
        tp= &t; 
    //}   // if the closing brace is present, object t calls destructor here!

    tp->join();
}
```

If you take a look into your STL you find the following code:

```
~thread()
{   
  if (joinable())
std::terminate();
}
```

That simply results in the call to the `terminate`.

So the example code has two mistakes:

1) Create a pointer to an object which dies before the pointer is used which is called `dangling reference`

2) Because thread object dies before join() was called, it simply calls terminate.

Comment: @DavidHaim: You are very fast :-) I need a minute to find the destructor of thread for pointing to the implementation;)

Answer (score 2):

a `std::thread` needs to be `join`ed or `detach`ed **before** its destructor runs.

since you didn't call any `detach` or `join` the `std::thread`'s destructor called `std::abort`.

in the first example, you first `join`ed the thread before actually calling its destructor (via `delete`):

```
 t[i]->join();
 delete t[i];
```

luckily for you, it prevented something much more worse: dangling pointers. in the end of each

```
 for(int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
        thread ti{f};
        t[i] = &ti;
    }
```

`ti` is dead, you keep a pointer to an object which does not live anymore. you violate some basic rule of C++ **never return or keep a pointer or reference to local variable outside its scope**